# any linear algebraic group rational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Somewhere in Mumford's GIT, he seems to imply that any linear algebraic group is rational? This seems strange to me. Is it true?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A (reduced, irreducible) linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field is rational -- i.e., birational to projective space.  This is a nontrivial result.

Briefest sketch of proof [EDIT: in characteristic 0 only; see the comment below]: use the Levi decomposition to reduce to the case of reductive groups, then use the Bruhat decomposition to handle the reductive case.

This does not hold for geometrically integral linear groups over an arbitrary ground field.  For instance, if $k$ is any field which admits a nondegenerate [i.e., degree $4$] biquadratic extension $l = k(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$, then the norm torus associated to $l/k$ is a three-dimensional nonrational algebraic torus.  I think this example is in some sense minimal.

See the [Springer Online Reference Works](http://eom.springer.de/R/r077670.htm) for more information, including references.

Comment: Can you give me a reference?

Comment: Sure, I edited my response to include one.

Comment: You should probably assume the group is connected....

Comment: Pete, the Levi decomposition is not true over alg. closed fields of positive characteristic.  Typical counterexample is $G(W_2(k))$ for a Chevalley group $G$.  See section A.6 of "Pseudo-reductive groups". 

Comment: Indeed, this example is minimal in the following sense: any connected one-dimensional or two dimensional  linear algebraic group over a field $k$ of characteristic 0 is $k$-rational. See my comment to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/90142/4149).

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rationality_theorems.

Answer (score 9):

Pete gave the general answer, but let me mention a simple linear algebraic reason this should not surprise you (again, let me work over an algebraically closed field):

Recall that GL_n is **almost** the product of a torus and two subgroups isomorphic to affine space, because of the Gauss decomposition: a generic invertible matrix is the product of a unique triple consisting of an upper triangular matrix with 1's on the diagonal, a diagonal matrix and a lower triangular matrix.  This is the birational map that Pete was referring to.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why unipotent groups are isomorphic to affine space. I know that they are a closed subset thereof.

Comment: For me, what was always the definition of a unipotent group, but look at the Springer Reference on "unipotent groups" it seems that things are trickier over characteristic p.  Of course, in GL_n, there's an easy proof that upper (or lower) triangular matrices are isomorphic to affine space.  The map is just looking at off-diagonal entries.

Comment: In characteristic zero, the exponential map between a nilpotent Lie algebra and the corresponding unipotent Lie group is an algebraic isomorphism. Hence, unipotent groups in characteristic zero are isomorphic to affine space. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10730/references-for-theorem-about-unipotent-algebraic-groups-in-char0

Answer (score 7):

This is really just Pete Clark's answer -- the new bit is to note that
the Levi decomposition isn't needed.

Let G be a (reduced, connected) linear algebraic group over an
alg. closed k, and let R be the unipotent radical of G. Choose a Borel
group B of G with unipotent radical U < B (so R < U).

There is a dense B-orbit ("big cell") V in G/B which is a rational
variety.

Since U and R are (split) unipotent, [Springer, LAG 14.2.6] shows that there
is a section $s:U/R \to U$ to the natural projection $U \to U/R$.

If $f:G \to G/B$ is the quotient mapping, using $s$ you can find a "local
section" of $f$ over the big cell V.

This show that $f$ is a locally trivial B-bundle (in the Zariski
topology) and in particular $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subvariety of G
isomorphic to the rational variety V x B.